# splitting a ManyToManyField over multiple form fields in a ModelForm

Tags: python, django, django-forms, modelform

So I have a model with a ManyToManyField called tournaments. I have a ModelForm with two tournament fields:

```
pay_tourns = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
                        queryset=Tourn.objects.all().active().pay_tourns(),
                        widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple())
rep_tourns = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
                        queryset=Tourn.objects.all().active().rep_tourns(),
                        widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple())
```

The methods after all() there are from a subclassed QuerySet. When I'm saving the form in my view I do thus:

```
post.tournaments = (post_form.cleaned_data.get('pay_tourns')
                                + post_form.cleaned_data.get('rep_tourns'))
```

Anyway, this all works fine. What I can't figure out how to do is fill these form fields out when I'm loading an existing post. That is, when I pass instance=post to the form. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Paolo Bergantino was on the right track, and helped me find it. This was the solution:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(MyForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    instance = kwargs.get('instance')
    if instance:
        self.fields['pay_tourns'].initial = [ o.id for o in instance.tournaments.all().active().pay_tourns()]
        self.fields['rep_tourns'].initial = [ o.id for o in instance.tournaments.all().active().rep_tourns()]
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like this to the ModelForm:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(MyForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    instance = kwargs.get('instance')
    if instance:
        self.fields['pay_tourns'].queryset.filter(post=instance)
        self.fields['rep_tourns'].queryset.filter(post=instance)
```

I don't see why that wouldn't work, but I'm going to test it just to make sure...

**EDIT:** Tested and it works.

Comment: that works, but it doesn't do what I need. Rather then limiting the queryset, I need to have the ones that are associated with the post checked. What this does is make sure that only the tourns that are associated with the post are options.